# Cannot transcode 3gpp video using Intel Inde software

Tags: android

I captured a video using H.263 codec by a native camera. If I try transcode it on Android 18+ MediaCode throws

```
Exception 
java.lang.IllegalStateException 
android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
```

MediaCodec has params and the same output codec/format

```
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bit rate);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, sample rate);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
```

All is ok with H.264 codec, mp4 format. Please help!